# Given a Euclidean domain with Euclidean function $\delta$ is it possible to bound $\delta(r+r')$ in terms of $\delta(r)$ and $\delta(r')$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-algorithm

I came across this while thinking about [another Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644324/generalisation-of-euclidean-domains). 
Essentially everything is said in the title:

> Let $R$ be a Euclidean domain and let $\delta$ be a Euclidean function for this domain. Is $\sup\lbrace\delta(r+r')\mid\delta(r),\delta(r')<n\rbrace <\infty$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$? Similarly one can ask weather $\sup\lbrace\delta(rr')\mid\delta(r),\delta(r')<n\rbrace <\infty$ for all $n$.

For the common euclidean domains $(\mathbb{K}[t], \mathbb{Z}[i], ...)$ this is easy to show, but at the moment i have no real idea how to generalize this.

Comment: Isn't the norm required to have $\delta(rr')=\delta(r)\delta(r')$? Since in that case, the second problem is trivial.

Comment: Euclidean norm is a euclidean stathm?

Comment: @vrugtehagel: No, one can require a euclidean norm to satisfy $\delta(rr')\geq\delta(r)$, but in general it is not clear, that we can get a multiplicative euclidean function (it seems that this is an open problem in reseach)

Comment: @Bernard: what do you mean with stathm? In this context an euclidan function is a function satisfying the Properties for the euclidean algorithm.

Comment: More or less the same thing as a euclidean function (except it can be generalised to values in an ordinal set). But the nam `norm` is confusing in this context.

Comment: Ok, in this case i just mean an euclidean function. I canged the name in the Original post.